# Invertibility, inverse, and line weight of big circulant matrices

Tags: matrices, inverse, random-matrices

I am generating a random square sparse binary circulant matrix, defined by its first row. 
The length of the matrix is 9857 bits, and each line contains 71 ones, the rest are zeroes.

I need to ensure that the generated matrix is invertible, because I need to invert it later.

1. How do I ensure invertibility for such a matrix or test it for invertibility to know if I need to regenerate?
2. Is there a good way to calculate an inverse matrix to this?
3. Is there any way to calculate/predict the line weight of this inverse matrix? Is there a way to calculate/predict the line weight of the result of multiplication of such matrices?

I am not really good at this, if you can go basic on me I'll be grateful.
I'll do this in MatLab at first. I would like to port it to C later, but if I can't, MatLab will be fine. Thanks

Comment: I assume that you are doing modulo-2 arithmetic. If you only need to invert the matrix only once, you may simply compute a row reduced echelon form. Call your matrix $C$ and let $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$. Then compute the row reduced echelon form of the augmented matrix $(C,e_1)$. If the result is in the form of $(I,x)$, then $C$ is invertible and $C^{-1}$ is the circulant matrix whose first column is $x$. The augmented matrix can be stuffed into an array of $9857\times\lceil(9857+1)/8\rceil$ bytes (approx. 11.6MB) long. Row operations can be performed bitwise and in-place.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you, you should probably add this as an answer.  Now I'm thinking about an algorhithm that would compute the $(I,x)$ without saving the whole $C$ in memory. That leads me here: the resulting inverse matrix can be defined by column $x$ but also by first row $x$. Would it not be possible to get the inverse by applying row operations only to the first rows of $(C, I)$ ? Using some algorhithm that computes a combination of rotations of $c_1$ needed to transform it to $(1,0,0...0)$ ? 
Please tell me if this logic is wrong.

Comment: Numerical linear algebra is not my expertise. So, take this with a grain of salt. I don't think you can only store one (or a few) rows and operate on them. The reason is that after a row operation, $C$ usually is no longer circulant.

Comment: OK. It worked on a small matrix done by hand, tho. Maybe just luck.